# Cannot get docker-machine to start using launchctl on OSX

Tags: macos, docker, launchctl

I am trying to start docker-machine using a launchctl. I have install docker-machine using the docker toolbox. Here is my plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.docker.machine.default</string>
        <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
        <dict>
            <key>PATH</key>
            <string>/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin</string>
        </dict>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>docker-machine</string>
            <string>start</string>
            <string>default</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

However I get this error, and I unsure how to solve it.

```
^[[Oct  1 11:08:00 lm com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.docker.machine.default[4157]): Service could not initialize: 14D136: xpcproxy + 13421 [1402][E34BADE4-4125-3886-AA5B-08E47BD0E884]: 0x2
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @pdoherty926 No unfortunately not. I'm still getting this error. I have to start docker-machine manually every time I turn my computer on. Are you having the same problem? If so then I will create an issue on docker-machine repo.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't able to get anything similar working. My current approach is to set Docker Quickstart Terminal as a Login Item, with some modifications to its start shell script.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never :)

The first argument in `ProgramArguments` (here: `docker-machine`) need to be an absolute path to `docker-machine` executable. For me, it should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.docker.machine.default</string>
        <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
        <dict>
            <key>PATH</key>
            <string>/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin</string>
        </dict>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/usr/local/bin/docker-machine</string>
            <string>start</string>
            <string>default</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Determine yours by running `which docker-machine`.