# How to schedule a run of “docker-compose,” on MacOS, using launchd

Tags: macos, scheduled-tasks, docker, launchd, launchctl

I'm building some software with `docker-compose`, for which I would like to run on a schedule.

So I need to schedule a run of `docker-compose up`, on MacOS (High Sierra, 10.13.3), using [launchd](http://www.launchd.info). This is the LaunchAgent configuration I'm using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>local.edgarlydata</string>

    <!-- This script, which calls "docker-compose up" also fails :/

    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Users/me/my/project/my-script.sh</string> -->

    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/usr/local/bin/docker-compose</string>
      <string>up</string>
    </array>

    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key> 
    <array>
      <dict> 
        <key>Hour</key> 
        <integer>19</integer> 
        <key>Minute</key> 
        <integer>18</integer> 
        <key>Weekday</key>
        <integer>3</integer>
      </dict>
    </array>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

And when the process is launched at the scheduled time, the system log gives me this error message. There's no reason as to ***why*** the failure is happening.

```
Aug 15 19:18:00 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (local.edgarlydata[5379]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
```

**EDITED** to add contents of a try with `/Users/me/my/project/my-script.sh`. No dice.

```
#!/bin/sh

sudo -u myuser /usr/local/bin/docker-compose up
```

I saw a similar [question here](https://superuser.com/questions/980878/cannot-get-docker-machine-to-start-using-launchctl-on-osx). But that was for `docker-machine`. `docker-compose` needs to start from a project directory. Needless to say, it doesn't solve the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know launchd, but I don't see anywhere the working directory, and your script doesn't cd. Are you sure you're in a directory with a docker-compose.yml when this runs?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, the contents of
`/Users/me/my/project/my-script.sh`

Should just be:

```
docker compose up
```

And the majority of your Docker configuration should go inside your project's `docker-compose.yml` file.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the contents of that try with `my-script.sh`. That doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

So I got this working, first by specifying the `StandardErrorPath` and `StandardOutPath`. Those logs let me see that there was an error in my **docker-compose** `working_dir` setting. It was previously docker's PWD, and I hard-coded it to just **/usr/app**

```
app:
  image: my/app:latest
  working_dir: /usr/app
  volumes:
    - .:/usr/app
  entrypoint: run app
```

My **myjob.plist** now looks like this. And this is working for me. Hope this helps others.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>local.myjob</string>

    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/Users/me/Projects/myproject/stderr.log</string>

    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Users/me/Projects/myproject/stdout.log</string>

    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/Users/me/Projects/myproject</string>

    <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
    <dict>
      <key>PATH</key>
      <string>/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin</string>
    </dict>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/usr/local/bin/docker-compose</string>
      <string>up</string>
      <string>-d</string>
    </array>

    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key> 
    <array>
       <dict> 
        <key>Hour</key> 
        <integer>9</integer> 
        <key>Minute</key> 
        <integer>30</integer> 
        <key>Weekday</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
      </dict>
    </array>
  </dict>
</plist>
```